# Promotion Order in C-like Languages

Tags: c, type-promotion

We know that types get promoted.  For example, if you write:

```
int i = 2;
double d = 4.0;
double result = i / d;
```

. . . then the `int` will get promoted to a `double`, resulting in `0.5`.  However, I wasn't able to find any information on what happens if promotion and evaluation order conflict (it's also surprisingly difficult to Google).  For example:

```
int i = 2;
int j = 4;
double d = 1.0;
double result = d * i / j;
```

In this example, the value depends on when promotion happens.  If `i` gets promoted before the division, then the result will be `0.5`, but if the result of `i / j` gets promoted, then integer division happens and the result is `0.0`.

Is the result of what happens well defined?  Is it the same in C++ and other C-derived languages?

Comment: "if promotion and evaluation order conflict"--how do you think they can conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the result of what happens well defined?

Yes.

> Is it the same in C++ and other C-derived languages?

For `C++` - yes. But *"C-derived languages"* is not that well defined, so it is hard to answer.

The order of evaluation of

```
d * i / j
```

is

```
(d * i) / j
```

So, first `i` gets promoted to `double` due to `d * i`.

Then, the result (`double`) has to be divided by `j`, so `j` gets promoted to `double`. So there are **two promotions**.

However, for

```
d + i / j
```

the order of operations is different. First, `i / j` division is done using integer arithmetics, and then the result is promoted to `double`. So there is only **one promotion**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe promotion oder is the same as order of operations. When the compiler sees the line

```
double result = d * i / j;
```

it breaks the line down into:

```
double result;
result = d * i;
result = result / j;
```

before transforming it into machine code.